# Prove that a sequentially compact $K\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is not connected iff ...

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $K$ be a sequentially compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Prove $K$ is not connected if and only if there are two nonempty disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $K$ with $A \cup B=K$ and a positive $\epsilon$ such that 
$d(u,v) < \epsilon$ for all $u \in A$ and $v \in B$. Is the assumption of sequential compactness necessary for the existence of such an $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sequential compactness is necessary. You cannot do this with

$$(-1, 0) \cup (0,1)$$

for instance, where we do not have sequential compactness.

If you're now thinking closed-ness is the only problem here is another example to show that we really do need both closed and bounded:

$$\left\{ (x,y) : y = \frac{1}{x} \right\} \cup \left\{ (x,y) : y = 0\right\}$$

provides an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This set is closed, however it cannot be written as two disjoint sets which have a positive distance apart.

Answer (score 0):

$\to :$ Let$\ K=(K\cup U)\cap (K\cup V)$ for disjoint open set U, V.Then $\ A=(K\cup U)\ and\ B=(K\cup V)$ satisfy the condition. Let's show. Assume that the condition does not hold. So we can take$\ u_k \in U, v_k \in V,$ such that $d(u_k,v_k)\le\frac{1}{k}$ every positive integer k. By the Sequential compactness of K, There exists a subsequence$\ u_{k_j}\to u \in K.$ It is clear $v_{k_j}$ also goes to u.

However, if u is in U, since U is open, there exists r>0,$\ B_r(u) \subseteq U.$ But this is a contradiction becuase $\ v_{k_j}\to u$ but$\ v_{k_j} \notin U.$ Simiraly, u is not in V, hence u is not in K, contradiction for subsequential compactness of K.

$\\$

$\gets:  f(x) =\begin{cases} 0,  & \text{if $x \in A$ } \\ 1, & \text{if $x \in B$}\end{cases}$ 
$f$ is continous on K (take $d(x,a)<\epsilon$ then $f(x)$ is constant)
However, $f$ does not have intermediate value property, so K is not conected.

$\\$

For assumption of sequential compactness, use Deven Ware's answer, (-1,0)$\cup$(0,1).